# How can I correctly write the expansion $g(x) = \|y\|^2 -2 \langle y,x \rangle + \|x\|^2$ in summation form?

Tags: summation, binomial-theorem

Let $x$ and $y$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Define the function $g$ to be
$$
g(x) = \|y-x\|^2.
$$
This function can be expanded out as
$$
g(x) = \|y\|^2 -2 \langle y,x \rangle + \|x\|^2.
$$
I would like to write this in the binomial expansion type format:
$$
g(x) = \sum_{j=0}^2 \begin{pmatrix}2\\j\end{pmatrix}(-1)^j||x||^j||y||^{2-j}.
$$
However this summation is equal to
$$
\sum_{j=0}^2 \begin{pmatrix}2\\j\end{pmatrix}(-1)^j\|x\|^j\|y\|^{2-j} = \|y\|^2 -2 \|y\| \ \|x\| + \|x\|^2,
$$
which is not the same as the original expansion because the second term is a multiplication of norms instead of an inner product.

So is there some notation that accounts for this situation? How can I represent the original expansion of $g(x)$ in the form:

$$
g(x) = \sum_{j=0}^2 \begin{pmatrix}2\\j\end{pmatrix}(-1)^j???
$$

Similarly, for $\|y-x\|^4$ we have the expansion
$$
|x+y|^4 = |y|^4 - 4 \langle x, y\rangle|y|^2 + (2|x|^2|y|^2 + 4\langle x, y \rangle^2) - 4 \langle x, y\rangle|x|^2 + |x|^4,
$$
And again there is a visible correspondence with the regular binomial expansion. But does there exist notation that makes it possible to put it in a binomial type summation form?

Comment: $||x-y||^2$ is not the square of a binomial so you cannot pretend to express it with the binomial formula.

Comment: @EmilioNovati If you look at the $||y-x||^2$ or the $||y-x||^4$ cases there is a clear progression terms of powers of $x$ (or $y$)..e.g. $x^0, \langle x, \cdot \rangle, |x|^2 + \langle x, \cdot \rangle^2, \langle x, \cdot \rangle|x|^2, |x|^4$..The $n=2$ and $n=4$ cases can be written out explicitly, but I need to write it for $n \to \infty$ so I need some notation that can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comment we cannot pretend to use the binomial formula in this case.

You have noted a ''similitude'' and we can see how this come from.

I suppose that we are using the $2-$norm, so we have:
$$
||x-y||=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-y_i)^2}
$$

and:
$$
||x-y||^2=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-y_i)^2=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i^2+y_i^2-2x_iy_i)=||x||^2+||y||^2-2 \sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i=
$$
and here it is clear because the binomial formula does not work, but we have:

$$||x-y||^2=||x||^2+||y||^2-2\langle x,y\rangle
$$

Now we ca extend this result to  any integer power $n$ as:
$$
||x-y||^n=\sqrt{\left[\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-y_i)^2\right]^n}=\sqrt{\left[(||x||^2+||y||^2-2\langle x,y\rangle)\right]^n}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, however, I need to specifically write it in the form of a summation $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \dots$. I wrote out the explicit expansions for $n=2$ and $n=4$ above to make it clear that there is a correspondance with the binomial expansion, as the binomial expansion can be written as a summation in which the $x$ and $y$ variables are separated. So is it possible to write the generalized version as a summation in which $x$ and $y$ are separated?

Comment: Viewed as an approximation, the $||y||^2$ term gives the 0-th order approximation, the $-2\langle x, y \rangle$ term gives the 1-st order correction, etc..so I need to write it as summation for arbitrary $n$ as then I can truncate it at some number p and have a p-th order approximation. It's frustrating as I already have it coded, I just can't write it out!